# Get multiple rows from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT           USERINFO.UserID
                ,SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateFrom, DateTo) + 1) AS total_leave_days
FROM            USERINFO 
INNER JOIN      CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID 
left join       AuthLeave on AuthLeave.userid = userinfo.userid
                and AuthLeave.DATEFROM>='2014-01-01' 
                and AuthLeave.DATETO<='2014-06-30'

WHERE           (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= '2014-01-01') 
                AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME <= '2014-06-30') 
                AND  DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = 'GEN/SUP-TBL'

GROUP BY        USERINFO.UserID
```

here is my code from  this i can get below out put

```
UserID  total_leave_days
35      NULL
350     NULL
30      NULL
10      735
167     NULL
21      920
1       621
224     NULL
```

so it is not correct my Authleave table data is below:

```
UserID         DATEFROM           DATETO
 1            2014-03-10     2014-03-15 
 10           2014-05-28     2014-05-29
 21           2014-05-27     2014-05-27 
 1            2014-04-10     2014-04-15
```

from now i want output like below:

```
UserID  total_leave_days
    35      NULL
    350     NULL
    30      NULL
    10      2
    167     NULL
    21      1
    1       12
    224     NULL
```

so how can i do this ?

Comment: change `left join AuthLeave on AuthLeave.userid = userinfo.userid` to `inner join AuthLeave on AuthLeave.userid = userinfo.userid`

Comment: no its not working..

Comment: this left join should be above ur left outer join...

Comment: Are you sure there aren't more rows in `CHECKINOUT` per UserID for example? That could cause the higher numbers. Could you post the DDL of all the tables involved?

Comment: what about the sample tables of `CHECKINOUT` and `DEPARTMENTS`? If possible you should try making some [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try This SQL

```
SELECT      U.[UserID],
            C.[Leave]
FROM        [USERINFO] U 
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT     [UserID],  
                        SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,[DATEFROM],[DATETO])) [Leave]
            FROM        [CHECKINOUT]
            WHERE       [CHECKTIME] >= '2014-01-01' AND [CHECKTIME] <= '2014-06-30'
            GROUP BY    [UserID]
            ) C ON U.[USERID] = C.[USERID]
LEFT JOIN   [DEPARTMENTS] D ON D.[DEPTID] = U.[DEFAULTDEPTID] 
LEFT JOIN   [AuthLeave] A on A.[userid] = U.[userid]
WHERE       D.[DEPTNAME] = 'GEN/SUP-TBL'
enter code here
```

---

Edit:

See the below SQL, I got a bit confused by Table Names.

```
SELECT      U.[UserID],
            L.[Leave]
FROM        [USERINFO] U 
JOIN        CHECKINOUT C ON U.USERID = C.USERID 
LEFT JOIN   [DEPARTMENTS] D ON D.[DEPTID] = U.[DEFAULTDEPTID] 
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT     [UserID],  
                        SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,[DATEFROM],[DATETO])) [Leave]
            FROM        [AuthLeave]
            WHERE       [DATEFROM] >= '2014-01-01' AND [DATETO] <= '2014-06-30'
            GROUP BY    [UserID]
            ) L ON L.[UserID] =U.[UserID]
WHERE       D.[DEPTNAME] = 'GEN/SUP-TBL'
AND         C.[CHECKTIME] >= '2014-01-01' AND C.[CHECKTIME] <= '2014-06-30'
```

Comment: give error - Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'DATEFROM'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'DATETO'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME" could not be bound.

Comment: What are the column names of table CHECKINOUT?

Comment: CHECKTIME is the column name

Comment: You'll have to alias your subquery